# Blender crash at startup on Ubuntu

Tags: linux

After installing via apt, trying to run for the first time on a new Ubuntu 16.04 LTS installation with NVDIA-375 drivers, Blender crash suddenly with this crash report:

```
# Blender 2.76 (sub 0), Commit date: 1970-01-01 00:00, Hash unknown

# backtrace
blender(BLI_system_backtrace+0x30) [0x1361b10]
blender() [0x97a98e]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x354b0) [0x7fe5348694b0]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0xaa0bd) [0x7fe5348de0bd]
blender(gpu_extensions_init+0xf3) [0xf63363]
blender(GPU_init+0x20) [0xf65a10]
blender(WM_init+0x106) [0x98b0e6]
blender(main+0xd2e) [0x95cc3e]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf0) [0x7fe534854830]
blender(_start+0x29) [0x97a2b9]
```

Ubuntu declares a crash in GPU extensions.

Comment: I suggest you to install it from the archive (you find them all here http://download.blender.org/release/), as I ususlly do - there you'll find more recent versions.

Comment: After the last `sudo apt upgrade` I had to restart the system, and now it is working.

Answer (score 1):

For some sort of reason, after the last Ubuntu update and before installing Blender, something was changed in the GPU drivers that made the software to not startup correctly. Restarting the system fixed the problem.